# Call a locally hosted server from Expo

Tags: reactjs, expo, native, localtunnel

I have followed this great blog post: [How to call a locally hosted server from Expo?](https://dsinecos.github.io/blog/How-to-call-a-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app)

However I get stuck at the next step:

> The above command will return a URL accessible across Internet of the form https://application-mock-server.localtunnel.me. **This URL can be plugged inside the React Native code base** and will be accessible from the application running inside Expo on the mobile.

I have tried to figure out how to "plug the localtunnel URL inside the React Native code base". I thought that it would be "homepage" in "package.json", but so far no luck. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I haven't noticed this "tunnel" option until now, which does the trick.

[image]

Comment: Where is these options? On expo go mobile app? I could not see anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that URL where you are sending API request. If you have not created a separate file, you can create `apiConfig.js` file or any similar named file and export that URL from the file and reference where ever you need to call the backend API.